# Filter the JIRA Components based on Issue Type

Tags: jira, devops, jira-plugin

I have created some issues like,
     1. IT Issue
     2. RT Issue
     3. Bug
     4. Task and also 
 I have created the components like,
     1. Hardware
     2. Software
     3. Design
     4. Database.

1. if i select IT Issue and then these components (Hardware and Design) should display.
2. if i Select Bug and then these components (Software and Database) should display in components.

**How can i do this ?**

Comment: Hi, you might want to ask that question in https://devops.stackexchange.com/ instead

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't. There's only one list of components for all issue types across a project. There's [a feature request](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-9309), but it seems this feature has not been selected for development.